# Hide links after the current day

Tags: php, time

I'm currently building Advent calendar, and as you know, only 24 days are shown. Each of the day has a link that will shown its page.

**I'm trying to show links only to the pages from day 1 to current day, not after current day.**

For example, If today is 20 December, the rest (21, 22, 23, 24 December should have no link, no a href)

Here's how my code looks right now:

```
$date = date('Y-m-d');
echo 'Current Date: '.$date.'<br>';

for ($x = 1; $x <= 24; $x++) {          
        echo "<a class='grid-item' href=".'/region.php?region=Region&tag=2016-12-'.str_pad($x, 2, "0", STR_PAD_LEFT)."><em>$x</em></a><br>";
}
```

The output right now:

```
Current Date: 2016-11-11 
1
2 
3  
4 
5 
.. 
.. 
24
```

Any suggestion would be appreciated.

Comment: `if($date >= $currentdate)
 {
 echo "<a class='grid-item' href=".'/region.php?region=Region&tag=2016-12-'.str_pad($x, 2, "0", STR_PAD_LEFT)."><em>$x</em></a><br>";
 }

else
{
  echo "<a class='grid-item' href="#"><em>$x</em></a><br>";
}`

Comment: Well write a test in the loop and output something different if `$x > todays day`

Comment: Welcome to SO.
Please read [What topics can I ask about](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)
and [How to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)
And [the perfect question](http://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/)
And how to create a [Minimal, Complete and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

SO is **not a free Coding or Code Conversion or Debugging or Tutorial or Library Finding service**
___Here at SO we fix your attempts, we do not attempt your coding___

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just compare `$x` to the day of the month. If it is greater than it, don't show the link.

```
$today = new DateTime();
$day   = $today->format('j');
echo 'Current Date: '.$today->format('Y-m-d').'<br>';

for ($x = 1; $x <= 24; $x++) {  
    if ($x <= $day) {        
        echo "<a class='grid-item' href=".'/region.php?region=Region&tag=2016-12-'.str_pad($x, 2, "0", STR_PAD_LEFT)."><em>$x</em></a><br>";
    }
    else {
        echo $x;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you John! :)